# Inverse Sine, Cosine, and Tangent on Ubuntu Calculator

Tags: calculator, gnome-calculator

I am studying Physics, and I need a calculator that has Sine, Cosine, and Tangent. Ubuntu Calculator(gnome-calculator) is a pretty good choice for me because it has all kinds of capabilities. But there is only one problem. I cannot find the <kbd>sin<sup>-1</sup></kbd>, <kbd>cos<sup>-1</sup></kbd> and <kbd>tan<sup>-1</sup></kbd> buttons.

Calculator Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *Inverse* (<kbd>x<sup>-1</sup></kbd>) button:

[image]